# Insert animation into shaped div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I must admit I'm less than a genius in CSS... To practice, I'm creating an animation that simulates a beer glass.

For the moment, looking at some examples, I've achieved the desired animation: 
http://jsfiddle.net/yfb1fo8c/1/

And the shape I want:

```
#liquid {
    background: black;
    border-bottom: 500px solid #e39700;
    border-left: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    width: 300px;
    color: #fff8eb;
    position: absolute;
    clip:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

But when I try to merge both ideas my shape totally crashes, or is not animated: http://jsfiddle.net/ogpqj2kr/2/

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you realized that your desired animation code works in webkit-based browsers only? For a moment I was confused at what you wanted to achieve when I viewed it in Firefox until I saw the code which uses webkit prefixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/cqa7rfu7/ ?

(Sorry I'm not giving more details as I had to change a lot of stuff. Basically, your 'cup' had no height so you didn't see the waves. I did more changes anyway.)

Here's your new CSS :

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: black;
}

#foam {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: white;
    width: 460px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index:1;
}

#liquid {
    background: #000;
    width: 460px; height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    clip:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    z-index:2;
    background-image: 
    -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      left bottom,
      left top,
      color-stop(0, rgb(0,50,150)),
      color-stop(0.50, rgb(0,150,255))
    );
}

#liquid:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 500px 80px 0 0;
    border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent;
    z-index: 10;
}
#liquid:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 80px 500px 0;
    border-color: transparent #000000 transparent transparent;
    z-index: 10;
}

.wave{
    bottom:0;
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    height:10%;
    width:10px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-animation-name:             dostuff; 
    -webkit-animation-duration:         3s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    z-index:3;
}


@-webkit-keyframes dostuff{
    0%, 100% {
        height:10%;
    }
    50% { 
        height:20%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem are those borders that you are using, it push the content and that's why you cant see your animation, is not that is broken it's that you can only see the border.

I recommend you to use a **wrapper**, find a proper technique to shape that wrapper and then insert inside your liquid template.

I take your code and update to [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/thematho/o8fojg3q/1/). First i rotate the wrapper into `45deg` using `transform: rotate(45deg);` and then i rotate the element in the opposite angle: `transform: rotate(-45deg);` for compensate transformation on the wrapper.

You can achieve this behavior in different ways but try to use transform or `border-radius`, even `box-shadow`, any element that doesn't push the inner 
content

[In this presentation](http://lea.verou.me/humble-border-radius/#shapes) you can find several shapes that you can achieve using `border-radius` and combine them with transforms like i did rotating the wrapper and doing the opposite with the inner element

**Update:**

Fixed working example, wasn't importing jQuery correctly